# How to properly resize a WebView control for windows phone 8.1?

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1

Okay so I'm trying make a web browser and am stuck at this problem (pictures included.)

When the WebView control is in portrait mode, it works fine. When the phone rotates to the side it get's a squashed and messed up. Any ideas what's happening?

All I have the webview control to do is auto stretch to the screen size when it rotates.

Here's some pictures of the problem:

Now the application in Portrait view:

[image: Portrait]

Now the application in Landscape view:

[image: Landscape]

Comment: When you say "squashed" do you mean like how it zooms in, and the menu icon in the top looks funky?

Comment: it keeps the same size as when it's rotated vertically. kinda like it's not resizing to the proper width of the screen it 'stretches' and looks squashed

Comment: I have an idea, I'm going to work on a test javascript for you...

Comment: What is the width and height on this page before and after you rotate? https://jsfiddle.net/2pfdcxtk/embedded/result/

Comment: ....I never knew any of that. I don't know! wow I'm dumb. maybe it's just a screen size issue

Comment: I don't think you're dumb! There's the possibility that zoom is changing, and/or the possibility that we can alter the behavior to be closer to what you expect.